# Zero balance showing in Bitcoin client

Tags: balance

Yesterday i baught 1 bitcoin and i got a confirmation email that the amount was send to my wallet...only my wallet shows 0.00 balance!...i did install the bitcoin client after i purchased my bitcoin...is that the problem?...
My bitcoin client is fully syncronized with the network and running...only my balance shows 0.00.

Is it still possible to transfer my bitcoins to my wallet even if the client was installed after i did my bitcoins purchase?...if so, how can this be done?...

Answer (score 2):

if you installed your client after you bought the coin... then which address did you supply for receipt of your coin? if the address you gave to the seller is not in your wallet, then it won't show up there...

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the confirmation email i received from Happy Coins after i did my purchase. The question remains how do i transfer my bitcoins into the client?.........here is the link...please visit...http://postimg.org/image/5iua4omej/

Comment: So, the bitcoin address that you gave them, the 17DUzuz..... address, where did you get it?

Comment: BTW: According to blockexplorer: http://blockexplorer.com/address/17DUzuzcgCEZF1wrAwCuRQMGGdJ1vNt7dm the coins were sent to the address you supplied. So the big question is, what is this address that you gave them? Also, how many blocks does your client currently show it has? If this address is indeed from your client, then the transaction will show up when you have 227240 blocks. Because the transaction is inside block 227240.